# Spring Security filter has multiple URL intercept mappings

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, interceptor

I was following this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

In the `spring-security-xml`

```xml
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>
```

And in the web.xml, we must define the actual filter

```xml
<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So I don't get this, we are mapping the interception to 2 urls in 2 places. To `/welcome*` and `/*`. Why we need both of these? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DelegatingFilterProxy` is not a Spring Security class. It is from Spring Web package.

> Proxy for a standard Servlet 2.3 Filter, delegating to a
>   Spring-managed bean that implements the Filter interface. Supports a
>   "targetBeanName" filter init-param in web.xml, specifying the name
>   of the target bean in the Spring application context.

When you use

```
<http auto-config="true">

</http>
```

Spring Security creates (implicitly) bean with name `springSecurityFilterChain` (that's why you have `<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>` in your `web.xml`) and all requests (`/*`) are processed by it (by Spring Security).

Then you configure Spring Security and give it more specific URL (`/*welcome`).

```
<intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

It's like saying:

- All URL requests (`/*`) should be investigated by Spring Security
- When URL matches `/welcome*` principal should have `ROLE_USER` role.

If your application requires more advanced security processing you can create that filter chain bean by yourself and configure all filters manually.

Example:

```
<!-- Filter Chain -->
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/favicon.ico"
                              filters="none"/>

            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/img/**"
                              filters="none"/>

            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" 
                 filters="bannedIPsFilter, <!-- custom filter -->
                         channelProcessingFilter,
                         securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                         concurrentSessionFilter,
                         logoutFilter,
                         secondAuthenticationFilter, <!-- custom filter -->
                         openIDAuthenticationFilter,
                         usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter,
                         anonymousAuthenticationFilter,
                         captchaFilter, <!-- custom filter -->
                         sessionManagementFilter,
                         exceptionTranslationFilter,
                         filterSecurityInterceptor,
                         switchUserProcessingFilter"
                    />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Nice and thorough answer - must be helpful to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your nice words!

Comment: Great answer. What happens when a URL matches multiple filter-chain mapping. Is the first one the only one used?

Answer (score 0):

`springSecurityFilterChain` is a facade for all spring-security filters inside this filter-chain. It is registered as separate servlet filter in web.xml.

`/welcome*` - is a configuration for spring-security-specific "inner" filters, it's not present in web.xml and servlet container doesn't know anything about it.